# a command that tells if a username/password combination is a valid user

Tags: linux, login

I'm writing a bash script, and I need to validate when a user enters their unix username and password, that it's the same username and password they use to login. I was thinking of calling login, but I can't find a way to get it to exit immediately returning 0 (success) instead of spawning their normal shell.

Is there another command I can use? Any other ideas?

Comment: Will the script run in the users's context, or will it be running as root?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28812/is-it-possible-to-test-user-name-and-password

Answer (score 1):

A lot of possible answers and programming/script languages are [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28812/is-it-possible-to-test-user-name-and-password) including bash also.